# Reducing a 2D array taking into account another 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have two 2D arrays with identical elements but in a different order. I want to filter one taking into account if it already exists in the second array.
Examples of both arrays:

```
const firstArray = [['45614726','2020-4-28'],['45610125','2020-4-28'],['45880944','2020-4-28'],['43452341','2020-4-28']] // there are like 40 arrays inside, not sorted

const secondArray = [['34347896', '2020´4-30'],['45614726','2020-4-28'],['45610125','2020-4-28'],['45880944','2020-4-28'],['45892916','2020-4-28']] // there are like 300 arrays inside, not sorted
```

I want to eliminate the arrays of the "secondArray" that have the first index repeated in the "firstArray".

```
secondArray =[['34347896', '2020´4-30'], ['45892916','2020-4-28']]
```

I tried several things, I know that the most useful action is to use .reduce but it seems that I cannot make it work.

```
const notPosted = secondArray.reduce((a, b) => {
                if (!firstArray[a[0]]) a.different.push(b);
                return a;
            }, {different: []});
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have to find in array, use array.find

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could convert your 2D array into an object with the zero index of each nested array being the key, and the first index being the value. (i.e. you already have your array in the perfect form for this `[[key, val], [key, val], ...]`)

This is easy with `Object.fromEntries(firstArray);`

Then you call a simple filter function on your second array and return only those that have a key that is not in the object (lookups of keys in an object are fast - hash tables)

```js
// there are like 40 arrays inside, not sorted
const firstArray = [['45614726','2020-4-28'],['45610125','2020-4-28'],['45880944','2020-4-28'],['43452341','2020-4-28']]

// there are like 300 arrays inside, not sorted
const secondArray = [['34347896', '2020´4-30'],['45614726','2020-4-28'],['45610125','2020-4-28'],['45880944','2020-4-28'],['45892916','2020-4-28']];

const firstObj = Object.fromEntries(firstArray);

const secondFiltered = secondArray.filter(([key,val]) => !firstObj.hasOwnProperty(key));

console.log(secondFiltered);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which one is faster:

```js
const arr1 = [['45614726','2020-4-28'],['45610125','2020-4-28'],['45880944','2020-4-28'],['43452341','2020-4-28']]

const arr2 = [['34347896', '2020´4-30'],['45614726','2020-4-28'],['45610125','2020-4-28'],['45880944','2020-4-28'],['45892916','2020-4-28']];

//First solution:
console.log("1) ",arr2.filter(e=>!arr1.some(e2=>JSON.stringify(e2)==JSON.stringify(e))))

//Second:
console.log("2) ",arr2.filter(e=>!arr1.some(e2=>e[0]==e2[0]&&e[1]==e2[1])))
```